# Função ou Método para Reiniciar um aplicação no console C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Existe alguma função disponível ou método para Reiniciar a aplicação no console C#?

```
static void decision()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Press the home key to recalculate. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue);
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.WriteLine(" Press the esc key to exit. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta);
        Console.ResetColor();

        var option = Console.ReadKey();

        if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Home)
        {
            /* reiniciar aplicação console aqui */
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n Invalid option, try again!", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red);
            Console.ResetColor();
            decision();
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que é reiniciar a aplicação? Melhor dizer o que precisa em vez de tentar fazer algo aleatório, provavelmente não precisa do que está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser reiniciado finalizando o processo atual e criando um novo.

Como não especificou em qual Framework está utilizado, eu tomei a liberdade de exemplificar em .NET Core

```
 class Program
    {
        static bool flag;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
            while (!flag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Press the home key to recalculate. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue);
                Console.ResetColor();

                Console.WriteLine(" Press the esc key to exit. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta);
                Console.ResetColor();

                var option = Console.ReadKey();

                if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Home)
                {
                    Process.Start("cmd", $"/c dotnet {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location}");
                    flag = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Invalid option, try again!", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }

        }

        private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

O evento `Console_CancelKeyPress` é acionado somente quando as teclas Ctrl+C é pressionado.

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas alternativas para se obter o resultado que deseja.
A primeira que posso pensar é voce criar um método a parte e chama-lo novamente

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            run();
        }
        static void run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Press the home key to recalculate. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue);
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.WriteLine(" Press the esc key to exit. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            Console.ResetColor();

            var option = Console.ReadKey();

            if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Home)
            {
                run();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n Invalid option, try again!", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red);
                Console.ResetColor();

            }
        }
    }
```

A outra seria simplesmente colocar dentro de um laço de repetição while

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n Press the home key to recalculate. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue);
                Console.ResetColor();

                Console.WriteLine(" Press the esc key to exit. . .", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta);
                Console.ResetColor();

                var option = Console.ReadKey();

                if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (option.Key == ConsoleKey.Home)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Invalid option, try again!", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red);
                    Console.ResetColor();

                }
            }
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```